# GridView Events Clarification

Tags: asp.net, events, gridview

Recently I have been asked an interview question "*What are the events order in GridView?*".

I explained

- Init()
- Loading()
- DataBinding()
- DataBound()
- RowCreated
- .... User interaction events like RowCommand,RowDeleting,RowUpdating
- PreRender -executes every time when the GridView is modified
- unload()

I would like to check whether my answer is right or  not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following list was obtained by creating an event handler for all events available in 
the Gridview's design mode in VS.Net and placing the following in the handler:

```
Debug.WriteLine("EventName");
```

Init

DataBinding

RowCreated

RowDataBound

DataBound

Load

(Action Events) (i.e - SelectedIndexChanging, SelectedIndexChanged)

PreRender

Unload